# How to have a storageclass that uses the filesystem of the VM that docker desktop runs in?

Tags: docker, minikube, docker-desktop

I am having trouble mounting minio to a volume on my host machine that runs on ubuntu 22.04 (even with O_DIRECT and O_DSYNC enabled). On the other hand if I run minio using docker desktop and does not declare a volume mount, docker desktop will handle it on its own and create a volume on the VM that docker desktop uses (that is good enough for my purpose). So I was wondering if it is possible to have on minikube that uses docker driver a storage class that uses the filesystem of the VM that docker desktop uses.

Comment: If you have an Ubuntu host, do you actually need Docker Desktop?  Does eliminating its hidden Linux VM resolve your issues?  Minikube already has a [storage provisioner](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/#dynamic-provisioning-and-csi), and maybe the thing you want for your immediate question is to use a directory that isn't [shared](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/linux/#file-sharing)?

Comment: @DavidMaze I ended up using docker desktop because I understood it adds extra security and also I try to have the same setup in my macos laptop. I guess eliminating that might resolve the issue and I could have the volume in the host. And you are right, I just have to use the csi hostpath because standard does not work on multi node minikube. And I also was having trouble accessing the VM, but I found the way and the volume was working, with the files been mirrored to /var/lib/docker/volumes/minikube/_data.